# Can not call/run/execute ruby script from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I wanna run a ruby script which will be invoked by a method aftest of a controller.
when excuting controlle we know the current path is at the root of project.

FullScanTest.rb : the script i wanna invoke.
i can run the following command in bash shell , but can not invoked in rails
ruby ./public/ruby_lib/af/FullScanTest.rb -i 172.16.178.178 -s 25_10_1 -f auto 
so i wrote a simple ruby script , which only reply a string . it did work~
ruby ./public/ruby_lib/af/test.rb
it works both on bash-shell and rails.

so what the problem?
permission?   setting ?

Thanks you all in advance~
is there anyway to get the error output when we invoked a script on ROR , 
i think it doesn't show the error msg.

i found the ruby script stop at require 'mechanize' and 'nokogiri'.(so i mark them ~ they won't be used in my app)
however the script also stop at somewhere not in expectaion , 
is there any limit to run a script?
the script will run for many hours.
i can  execute the command `ruby ./public/ruby_lib/af/FullScanTest.rb -i 172.16.178.178 -s 25_10_1 -f auto`  under prj_root

```
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'rubygems'

  require 'mechanize'

  require 'logger'
  require 'time'
  require 'nokogiri'
  require 'pp'
```

**
is there anyone to show error , when i call a ruby script by a controller? 
it's hard for me to debug, it didn't show any information.
**

```
def aftest

af_lib="./public/ruby_lib/af/"
prog="FullScanTest.rb"
prog2="test.rb"
params="-i 172.16.178.178 -s 25_10_1 -f auto "
cmd = " ruby #{af_lib}#{prog} #{params}  "
@cmd = %x[ echo #{cmd} ]
res1 = %x[ ruby #{af_lib}#{prog} ]
res2 = %x[ ruby #{af_lib}#{prog2} #{params} --force 2>&1 ]
@res1 = "#{res1}"
@res1 = "#{res2}"

end
```

i use the view to show the output , but it didn't show any errors

```
<h1>Af test lala</h1>

<%= form_tag :action => 'update', :id => @some_object %>
<%= form_tag( { :action => :save, }, { :method => :post }) %>
<h2>Command</h2>
<%= @cmd %>
<h2>Results</h2>
<%= @res1 %>
<h3>H3</h3>
<%= @res2 %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calling the script.  Seeing as the the only difference between the script that works and the script that doesn't, is the fact that the script that doesn't work has ARGUMENTS???

Do you use system to call the script?

i.e.

```
system("./public/ruby_lib/af/FullScanTest.rb","-i","172.16.178.178","-s","25_10_1","auto")
```

or even better

```
path = "#{Rails.root}/public/ruby_lib/af/FullScanTest.rb"
system(path,"-i","172.16.178.178","-s","25_10_1","auto")
```

Comment: yes , i did use system to call the script , it did work!! but can not run on rails . i wrote a simple ruby script called by a controller. it did work,too~

Comment: Look closely at my original post,  did you separate the arguments into individual arguments to system?  If so then I think you are now into the 'premissions' issue.  Does the script on the server have execute permission for the user account the web server runs under?

Comment: still not work ,  and i typed the command chmod -R 777 * undex prj_root . it still no work~~

Comment: i'm just curious . when we can call a ruby script on ROR . but can not catch any err message. how to debug? oh my god=_=

Comment: typing error.  cmd = " ruby #{af_lib}#{prog} #{params}       prog="FullScanTest.rb"
    prog2="test.rb"
    params=" -i 172.16.178.178 -s 25_10_1 -f auto " it works now~~ thank you for your support!!